# Hibernate: Mapping read only (static) lookup Entities Best Practice

Tags: hibernate, jpa

If we have a Dynamic Read Write Entity say Order `Class Order` which has a lookup attribute say `orderType`. `OrderType` is a lookup reference read-only table, where the entries may never change or say once a year or so.

What would be the best approach to mapping such attribute.

1) Should we map such an attribute like others. Advantage is simple to implement. Disadvantage. Unnecessary Joins in queries with lookups or additional queries fired to fetch lookup entities.

2) Should we simply not have any mapping in the `Order` (parent) class. And, fetch can Cache all the lookup entities initially and use it in the code where required? e.g., the `Order` class with only have `orderTypeId`. And can contain a method as follows

`getOrderType() 
{ return orderTypeCache.get(orderTypeId); }`

3) Should we use second level cache with first approach.

4) Any other best practice.

Comment: How if store OrderType as enum?

Comment: @MarufHassan Thanks for replying. Yes Enum is one option. However, if any new orderType gets added, we might need to change the Java Code.

Comment: Map it as anything else. Sometime, your static lookup entity will become a dynamic one. You probably won't have any performance issue related to these entities. If you really have one, then use the second-level cache to cache them, while still mapping them exactly like other entities.